# Use Mutter on Gnome Flashback

Tags: 20.04, mutter, gnome-flashback

I would like to use Mutter as a window manager on Gnome Flashback. According to GNOME website, this should be possible:

https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeFlashback

"Metacity: The window manager of GNOME Flashback, optionally other window managers such as mutter can be used but Metacity is the one thats officially supported."

Comment: With `mutter --replace` you replace the current widow manager with mutter. I am not sure that `can` in this case means "it can out-of-the-box" or "it can but only after spending many sleepless nights trying to do it". It might be that after replacing it, nothing works anymore (in that case, you can always switch to a `tty` and restart the `X` server)

Comment: It works! I tested it a few minutes watching a movie with VLC and it worked fine :)

Comment: Unfortunately `mutter` is not WM you might want to use with GNOME Flashback... `gnome-flashback` and `mutter` both will try to manage input settings, monitor configuration...

Comment: @muktupavels Ah too bad, since I would like to have VSync on Flashback, which Mutter gives. Compiz has it too iirc, but I would like something lighter than Compiz...

Comment: Now I'm using Ubuntu MATE (the best desktop) with Compiz. It's a good workaround until MATE has Wayland support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `mutter --replace` you replace the current widow manager with mutter.

I am not sure that `can` in this case means "it can out-of-the-box" or "it can but only after spending many sleepless nights trying to do it".

It might be that after replacing it, nothing works anymore (in that case, you can always switch to a `tty` and restart the `X` server)